# comments versus downvotes versus revenge

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

A downvote on an answer leads to a floater suggesting a comment. There's a hypothetical problem with this: if I dv and also comment, the subject now has a pretty good clue who dv-ed it. A sufficiently unhinged personage might then go off in search of anything and everything I've ever posted to return the favor.

I am a very infrequent downvoter, but I went ahead and did both just now, having encountered an answer with a flatly counterfactual statement, and now I'll see what happens.

I imagine that someone has suggested attaching anonymous comments to the anonymous downvotes to avoid this possibility.

Comment: "a floater" means the same thing there as it does here right?

Comment: I downvoted this question

Comment: See the answers to my question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes

Comment: @random -- no peas are involved.

Comment: What's better is when you see a downvoted post but nobody has posted a comment. You can then swoop in with your comment and look like you've downvoted them. Good times.

Comment: Also serial down-voting is checked for and reversed so you won't suffer for long.

Comment: This time the subject proves to be a complete sportsperson. He/she repairs their answer. So quickly, in fact, that I can't remove the downvote, due to the 5-minute business.

Comment: What exactly are you bringing up in this post and your subsequent comment?

Comment: I'm guilty of thinking out load about the working of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **never** down-vote, and add a comment at the same time. If the post really deserves both, I will add a comment, then at some point later, I will down-vote it. This happens very rarely though.

---

- If the post can be saved, I usually just post a comment indicating to the OP how to fix it.
- If I just don't agree with the answer, I will down-vote.
- If the post is just plain wrong, and the OP doesn't appear to care, I will do both.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comment, there are some checks to see if these sorts of things are happening. If you suspect that it has happened, and you don't see it reversed in a day or two, you have a couple of options:

- Flag the question you down-voted and in the box let the Mods know that you think the individual has revenge down-voted a bunch of your questions. They will look into it.
- Send an e-mail to the team at the address at the bottom of every page. They will look into it.